# If $a+b$ is even, then $a-b$ is even

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Prove that for all $a,b \in\mathbb Z$, if $a+b$ is even then $a-b$ is even.

I started off by assuming that a and $b$ are both odd integers, $2k+1$ and $2m+1$ such that their sum is $2(k+m+1)$ which is an even integer. I then concluded that $a-b$ is $2(k-m)$ which is also even, hence the statement is true.
My question is, is this enough to prove that the statement is true or do I also have to proof it when both $a$ and $b$ are even, and when one of $a$ and $b$ is even and the other is odd. Thanks.

Comment: odd+odd=even+even=even.
odd+even=odd.
parity of a number is independent of sign.

Comment: Just to say, a simpler argument follows at once from $a-b=(a+b)-2b$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is definitely a good start, but it is always a good idea to cover all possible cases, which means mentioning even and even, but also even and odd. I hope this helps!

Another way to proof it, is without using cases:
If $a+b$ is even, than there exists a whole number $n$ such that $a+b=2n$. If you substract $2b$ from both sides, you'll see that the result is $a-b=2n-2b=2(n-b)$. Which is even and that is exactly what you were trying to prove.

Answer (score 1):

So far you've only proved that the sum of two odd integers is even.  Try dropping that assumption and see what you can do, i.e. suppose $a + b = 2n$, for some integers $a,b,n$.  Can you get from that equation to an equation involving $a - b$?

Comment: I understand what you mean but I don't know how to formulate an equation for a-b

Comment: Is there anything you can do to both sides of the equation $a+b = 2n$ so that you end up with $a - b$ on the left?

Comment: -2b. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$a+b$ is even.

Assume $a-b$ is odd.

Add: $(a+b)+(a-b)=2a;$

Adding an odd number $(a-b)$ to an even number $(a+b) $ gives an even number $2a$. A contradiction.